# Ways to propagate changes to content children

Tags: angular

I'm trying to develop a good (maintainable, easy to reason about) way to propagate changes from a top-level parent to its content children.

Currently I trigger changes to the content children in `ngOnChanges` of the top-level parent which in turn triggers `ngOnChanges` of its content children and so on. I feel this is a bit clunky.

What are some alternatives I can use here? Thanks

```
<grandparent
  [inputOne]=""
  [inputTwo]=""
  [inputThree]=""
>
  <parent>
    <child>
    </child>
  </parent>
</grandparent>
```

grandparent.ts

```
@ContentChild(ParentComponent) parent: ParentComponent
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this.parent.ngOnChanges(changes);
}
```

parent.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {
  ... 
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.child.ngOnChanges(changes);
  }
}
```

child.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {
  ... 
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    switch(changes.currentValue) {
      case 'one':
        // handle changes
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators.

`@Input()` **lets a** **parent component update data in the child component**.

Conversely, `@Output()` **lets the child send data to a parent component**.

learn more in the documentation by angular:
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

**P.S.** if you want a grandparent to communicate with its grand kids, you have to pass by the original parents, it's not possible directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The grandparent template would be using `<ng-content select="parent"></ng-content>`. How would this variable be passed as scope for the ng-content (i.e. `ParentComponent`s) without using `ng-template`? From what I understand, you can't do this with `@Input`